# TriMatch R package gives me equal groups but one of them is larger than original group

Tags: r, sample-size, propensity-scores, matching

I am doing propensity score matching between 3 groups.
I am using `TriMatch` R package and it gives me equal groups (**118 in each group**) but 1 of them is larger than original group (918 in Control, 134 in Treat1 and **90 in Treat2** group).

My questions:

- Is this due to creation of **pseudo-population**?
- Is there any
  approach to limit that to maximum of 90 in Treat 2 ?

Code: [My data and matched transposed data](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZJGmlXZqKNm549K777DGCQISIu4h0nlauA7)

```r
##https://rdrr.io/cran/TriMatch/src/demo/tutoring.R
library(TriMatch); library(grid)
data(tutoring)

names(tutoring)
table(tutoring$treat)

formu <- ~ Gender + Ethnicity + Military + 
            ESL + EdMother + EdFather + Age +
            Employment + Income + Transfer + GPA

# Estimate the propensity scores for the three models
tutoring.tpsa <- trips(tutoring, tutoring$treat, formu)

# Prints a combined summary of the three logistic regression models
summary(tutoring.tpsa)

# In the three cases below we will use exact matching on the Course.
# Default maximumTreat
tutoring.matched <- trimatch(tutoring.tpsa, 
                      exact=tutoring[,c('Course')]) 

##### Checking balance #########################################################
multibalance.plot(tutoring.tpsa) + 
    ggtitle('Covariate Balance Plot')
##### Phase II #################################################################
matched.out1 <- merge(tutoring.matched, tutoring)
write.csv(matched.out1, file="matched.out1.csv")
```

Then I moved the obtained columns to be vertical rather than being horizontal in shape
(data is available in excel sheet named "matched.out_transposed")

```r
##########################################################################
##########################    Tableone SMD          ######################
##########################################################################
library(tableone); library(survey);   
    library(reshape2);library(testthat)
#==================================================================================
dput(names(data.matched.transposed))

Vars <- c("Course", "Gender", "Ethnicity", "Military", "ESL", 
    "EdMother","EdFather", "Age", "Employment", "Income",  
    "Transfer", "GPA")
Catvars <- c(   "Course", "Gender", "Ethnicity", "Military", 
               "ESL" )
NP.vars <- c( "Course", "EdFather",  "EdMother", "Age", 
              "Employment", "Income",  "Transfer", "GPA")

tab2 <- print( CreateTableOne(vars = Vars, 
                             data=data.matched.transposed,
                             strata = "treat",factorVars = 
                              Catvars, test = F),
                            nonnormal =NP.vars,dropEqual 
                            =T,showAllLevels =T, smd =T)
```